# Create a second class that uses the same database table as the first class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have class User : IdentityUser that is stored in database table 'dbo.Users'. I want to create a second class ApplicationUser, that also uses data from table 'dbo.Users', only the ApplicationUser would not use all of the columns.

How do I make two classes use the same database table, if that is even possible?

Comment: you can create a base class and inherit that class in a derived class or please elaborate what exactly you are  trying do

Comment: I have class User that inherits from IdentityUser, so it can't inherit from any more classes. But I have to add one more inherit class to User, so I created ApplicationUser, that will inherit that class, now the problem is that ApplicationUser creates an error because there is no table for applicationuser

Comment: Have you added a `TableAttribute` on the `ApplicationUser` class?

Comment: Sounds like a common use case for a view model (only needing a subset of the entity model).